# Условие if в ArrayList Java, Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Класс Field:

```
public class Field{
int id;
String content;
boolean good;

Student(int id, String content, boolean good){
    this.id = id;
    this.content= content;
    this.good= good;
  }
}
```

Метод заполнения ArrayList:

```
public static ArrayList<Field> getFields(){
ArrayList<Field> Fields = new ArrayList<Field>();

Field Newspaper = new Field (1, "New York Times", true);
Field Magazine = new Field(2, "My Best Photo", false);
Fields.add(Newspaper);
Fields.add(Magazine);
return Fields;
}
```

Метод, вызывающийся при нажатии кнопки:

```
public void onClicked() {
    String first_string = firstField.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("fieldStrings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

        ArrayList<Field> Fields = getFields();

        for (int i = 0; i < Fields.size(); i++) {
            if(first_string == Fields.get(i).content){
                editor.putString("id", String.valueOf(Fields.get(i).id));
                editor.apply();

                Intent next= new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
                next.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(Fields.get(i).id));
                next.putExtra("content", Fields.get(i).content);
                next.putExtra("good", String.valueOf(Fields.get(i).good));
                startActivity(next);
            }
    }
```

Нужно, чтобы при совпадении first_string и content в Shared Preferences добавлялся id, а в intent добавлялись все поля списка, в зависимости от индекса. После должен быть переход в NextActivity с данными intent.

Вопрос: во время отладки замечаю, что условие в цикле (if(first_string == Fields.get(i).content)) компилятор отмечает как false в любом случае, не важно, совпадает first_string с Fields.get(i).content или нет. Почему?

Comment: ибо строки сравнивают используя `equals()`. А `==` сравнивает объекты, которые заведомо разные. Исходя из этого и  отмечает как `false`

Comment: Да, точно, спасибо. Добавил ещё один вопрос

Comment: Может в цикл не заходит? массив пустой?

Comment: Нет, в цикл заходит и массив заполнен корректно. Он просто обновляет текущее Activity

Comment: Попробуйте выводить в лог, с помощью Log.d(), что бы быть точно уверенным, а так же попробуйте вызвать метод .trim() у ваших строк, что бы быть уверенным, что нет пробелов в конце и в начале

Comment: На первый вопрос вам ответили, удалите его и оставьте только тот код, который необходим для второго вопроса. А вообще нужно не добавлять вопрос в уже имеющийся, а задавать новый.